# Losing precision when moving to Spark for big decimals

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdecimal

Below is the sample test code and its output. I see that java bigDecimal stores all the digits where as scala BigDecimal is losing on precision and does some rounding off and the same is happening with spark. Is there a way to set the precision or say never round off. I do not want to truncate or round off in any case

```
val sc = sparkSession
import java.math.BigDecimal
import sc.implicits._

val bigNum : BigDecimal = new BigDecimal(0.02498934809987987982348902384928349)
val convertedNum: scala.math.BigDecimal = scala.math.BigDecimal(bigNum)
val scalaBigNum: scala.math.BigDecimal = scala.math.BigDecimal(0.02498934809987987982348902384928349)

println("Big num in java" + bigNum)
println("Converted " + convertedNum)
println("Big num in scala " + scalaBigNum)

val ds = List(scalaBigNum).toDS()
println(ds.head)
println(ds.toDF.head)
```

Output

1. Big num in java0.0249893480998798801773208566601169877685606479644775390625
2. Converted 0.0249893480998798801773208566601169877685606479644775390625
3. Big num in scala 0.02498934809987988
4. 0.024989348099879880
5. [0.024989348099879880]

Answer (score 1):

Based on spark.apache.org/docs

- The precision can be up to 38, scale can also be up to 38 (less or equal to precision). The default precision and scale is (10, 0).

here: https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/math/BigDecimal.html

But if you want in a simple way then how about convert it to `String` before 
converting to `DF or DS` in order to get the precise value. :)

Just try if you want :)